# Null value passed in insert query using prepare statement

Tags: java, jsp, prepared-statement

I'm getting following error when I'm going to upload data into database:

> com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@628599fa: insert into
>   gallery(file_path,ck_product_name)
>   values('D:\Admin_Panel\web\img\gallery\2.jpg',null)

I don't want null value passed to the database. I pass the field name in designing like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="uploadFile.jsp">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Product Name:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="span6 typeahead" id="typeahead" name="ck_product_name" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4"   reqired=""/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group"> 
            <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Gallery Image</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="uProperty" id="txtimage" required="required">
                <span>Image Size (698 X 352)</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And my uploadFile code is:

```
<%
int no1 = 1;


String saveFile = "";
String contentType = request.getContentType();
if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
    int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
    byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
    int byteRead = 0;
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
        byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
        totalBytesRead += byteRead;
    }
    String file = new String(dataBytes);
    saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
    saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
    saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, saveFile.indexOf("\""));
    int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
    String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1, contentType.length());
    int pos;
    pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
    int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
    int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
    File ff = new File("D:/Admin_Panel/web/img/gallery/" + saveFile);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);
    fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();
%><br>
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <td><b>You have successfully upload the file:</b>
            <%out.println(saveFile);%></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%
    Connection connection = null;
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vehiclehire?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
    PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
    String sv = request.getParameter("ck_product_name");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
        psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into gallery(file_path,ck_product_name) values(?,?)");
        psmnt.setString(1, ff.getPath());
        psmnt.setString(2, sv);
        out.println(psmnt);
        int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
        if (s > 0) {
            System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
%>
```

Please anyone solve this issue..

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Comment: Database code in your jsp, wow. You know having multiple classes doesn't cost any money or anything, right?

Comment: Sir i did not got you..I'm not pro at this time in jsp, So sir please talk in some simpler terms.